# Python: <lambda> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, nonetype

I am trying to call a function called `Add_user` from another function called `Edit_user_admin`, I'm pretty sure I have written everything correctly but I keep getting the same error.

```
  File "G:/PVH_work/PVH_program/ParkTheReal.py", line 395, in <lambda>
    Add_user = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Add User", command=lambda: Add_user(frame_27, data_dictionary)).grid(row=1, column=0)
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is the function `Edit_user_admin`:

```
def Edit_user_admin(form_item, data_dictionary, row_num):
    form_item.grid_forget()
    frame_27 = Frame(gui)
    frame_27.grid()

    MyProfile = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="My profile", command=lambda: My_profile_admin(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=0)
    TrainingRecord = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Training Record", command=lambda: Training_record_admin(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    Compare = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Compare", command=lambda: Compare_admin(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=2)
    EditUsers = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Edit Users", command=lambda: Edit_user_admin(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=3)
    Team = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="View/Edit Team", command=lambda: Team_admin(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=4)
    Logout = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Logout", command=lambda: Logout(frame_27)).grid(row=0, column=5)

    Add_user = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Add User", command=lambda: Add_user(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=1, column=0)
    Edit_user = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Edit User", command=lambda: Edit_user(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Remove_user = ttk.Button(frame_27, text="Remove User", command=lambda: Remove_user(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=1, column=2)
```

And here is the function `Add_user`:

```
def Add_user(form_item, data_dictionary, row_num):
    form_item.grid_forget()
    frame_28 = Frame(gui)
    frame_28.grid()

    #Declare variables for creating a new user account
    __Username  = StringVar()
    __Name      = StringVar()
    __Age       = StringVar()
    __Email     = StringVar()
    __DoB       = StringVar()



    MyProfile = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="My profile", command=lambda: My_profile_admin(frame_28, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=0)
    TrainingRecord = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="Training Record", command=lambda: Training_record_admin(frame_28, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=1)
    Compare = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="Compare", command=lambda: Compare_admin(frame_28, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=2)
    EditUsers = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="Edit Users", command=lambda: Edit_user_admin(frame_28, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=3)
    Team = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="View/Edit Team", command=lambda: Team_admin(frame_28, data_dictionary, row_num)).grid(row=0, column=4)
    Logout = ttk.Button(frame_28, text="Logout", command=lambda: Logout_so(frame_28)).grid(row=0, column=5)
```

I have had this error on other functions but I found that adding a '_' to the function I'm trying to call's name, and then adding them same name extension to the command worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned `None` to `Add_user`; `ttk.Button.grid()` returns `None`:

```
Add_user = ttk.Button(...).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

You should *not* use the same name for the button reference and the function; Python will use the local variable in this case, not the global function.

Use a different name, and call `.grid()` *separately*:

```
add_user_button = ttk.Button(
    frame_27, text="Add User", 
    command=lambda: Add_user(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num))
add_user_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

The same applies to the other buttons.

If, however, you are not using the `add_user_button` reference anywhere else, you can make it one line, but you don't have to bother about assigning the result:

```
ttk.Button(
    frame_27, text="Add User", 
    command=lambda: Add_user(frame_27, data_dictionary, row_num)
).grid(row=1, column=0)
```